# Fabricjs drawImage alternative

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, drawimage

I were looking for a `drawImage()` alternative for `fabric.js` lib, so I've made a `function`:

```
function drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height) {
  return new fabric.Image(img, {
    left: x,
    top: y,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    id: "rhino",
    clipTo: function (ctx) {
      ctx.rect(sx,sy,swidth,sheight); 
    }
  });
}
var imgElement = new Image();
imgElement.onload = function() {
  var imgInstance = drawImage(imgElement, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
  canvas.add(imgInstance);
}; 
imgElement.src = "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg";
```

**The result needs to be:**
[image: rhino]

But I don't get nothing with my custom function. Where is the problem?

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaxRqZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really know what you want to achieve, but using clipTo is not my advice, both for performance and complexity reasons.
Draw on a temp canvas the portion of image you need, then use this temp canvas a source for your fabricJS image.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

function drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height) {
      var tmpc = document.createElement('canvas');
      tmpc.width = swidth;
      tmpc.height = sheight;
      ctx = tmpc.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img,-sx,-sy);
      return new fabric.Image(tmpc, {
        left: x,
        top: y,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        id: "rhino"
      });
    }
    var imgElement = new Image();
    imgElement.onload = function() {
      var imgInstance = drawImage(imgElement, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
      canvas.add(imgInstance);
    }; 
    imgElement.src = "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg";
```

```html
<script src="http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500", height="500"></canvas>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find solution,

```
var canvas = ctx = '';
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.selection = false;
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawImage(imgPath, x, y, width, height) 
{ 
  fabric.Image.fromURL(imgPath, function(img) {
    img.set({
      left: x,
      top: y, 
      width: width,
      height: height,
      id: "rhino",
      clipTo: function (ctx) {
        ctx.rect(5,5,50,50); 
      }
    });
    canvas.add(img).renderAll().setActiveObject(img);
  });
}
var imgElement = new Image();
imgElement.src = "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg";
imgElement.onload = function() {
  drawImage(imgElement.src, 50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```

https://codepen.io/mullainathan/pen/wGpzvY

Comment: The result isn't cropped like the image i've posted before

Comment: @Mrz now you can get proper result.

Comment: That's not really the same result... and remember, this is a function so I need to be able to specify every parameter directly in the function